# Spring Integration JMS Adapter connecting with Topic in Jboss

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration JMS 4.1, configured the Topic in JBoss, then configured in Spring integration as below with concurrent consumer and maximum concurrent consumer equal to 1. But after ran the application,jboss shows as connected consumers are 2. Because of this, application getting same message in two times. I tried all the possibility,I could not make it. Please help me. I need to have only one consumer connection with Topic or need to receive message only once.

```
 <bean id="connectionFactory"  class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
 <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="myTargetConnectionFactory">
    </property>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10" />
    <property name="cacheProducers" value="false" />
<property name="cacheConsumers" value="false"/>
</bean>



  <bean id="myTargetConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="ConnectionFactory"/>
                <property name="jndiEnvironment">
                    <props>
                       <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
                       <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
                       <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">localhost:1199</prop>
                    </props>
              </property>
</bean>

<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter  pub-sub-domain="true" connection-factory="connectionFactory" channel="incomeChannel" destination-name="SampleSub"concurrent-consumers="1" max-concurrent-consumers="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this problem is to load the application context twice by mistake - once in the web context (dispatcher servlet) and once in the root context (context loader listener) in the web.xml.

Comment: Thanks, I need to check. In that case, how do we avoid this?

Comment: Ensure the configuration is not included (or imported) in both places.